# What's the proper redirect rule (to avoid redirect loop)

Tags: regex, apache, http, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect a broken filename 'artist_-*title'  to 'artist*-_title.zip'. I tried this in .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 artist_-_title artist_-_title.zip
```

I think I do understand what causes the loop, but I don't know much about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 artist_-_title$ artist_-_title.zip
```